# Finding low appearance count values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking at a column full of repetitive numbers. I want to find the numbers that occur less than twice and change the original number into 5000.

I've tried:
`df['Count'] = df['Count'].map(lambda x: 5000 if df['Count'][df['Count']==x].count()<2)`
and this is giving me a syntax error.

`df['Count'][df['Count']==x].count()`   this alone works so I'm assuming I did something wrong in the lambda function.

Comment: A python ternary takes the form `THIS if CONDITION else THAT`. You don't have the `else THAT` part.

Comment: Wow thanks it worked. How come some other lambda functions don't need the 'else' part? I've definitely seen those.

Comment: @calamari You may have seen list comprehensions or generator expressions but an "if" without "else" in the actual lambda body is not possible if not e. g. inside one of the aforementioned (or similar) expressions.

Answer (score 0):

try running this on the count column

```
df['Count'] = df['Count'].where(df['Count'] > 2, 5000)
```

Anywhere where count is `< 2` will be replaced with 5000.